# c.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a semantic visibility
but I have this error
I don't know what I'll pass to my function parameter

could someone help me how could i fix this?

```
const handleOverlayRef = (c) => {
  console.log(c);
  if (!overlayRect) {
    setOverlayRect({ overlayRect: _.pick(c.getBoundingClientRect(), 'height', 'width') })
  }
}
      <Visibility
        offset={80}
        once={false}
        onTopPassed={()=> stickOverlay()}
        onTopVisible={()=>unStickOverlay()}
        style={overlayFixed ? { ...overlayStyle, ...overlayRect } : {}}
      />

      <div ref={() => handleOverlayRef()} style={overlayFixed ? fixedOverlayStyle : overlayStyle}>
        <Menu
          icon='labeled'
          style={overlayFixed ? fixedOverlayMenuStyle : overlayMenuStyle}
          vertical
        >
          <Menu.Item>
            <Icon name='twitter' />
            Twitter
          </Menu.Item>

          <Menu.Item>
            <Icon name='facebook' />
            Share
          </Menu.Item>

          <Menu.Item>
            <Icon name='mail' />
            Email
          </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
      </div>
```

error:

> TypeError: c.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Comment: Seee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963089/react-element-getboundingclientrect-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we work with ref we should declare it first, like so:

```
    function Component = props => { 
           const myRef = React.useRef(); 

        const myMethod = event => {
           const {height, width, x, y} = myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
           console.log(height, width, x, y);
         }

        return (
       <div ref={myRef} style={overlayFixed ? fixedOverlayStyle : overlayStyle}>


       </div>
     )
 }
```

Comment: oops i did that but i'm a little confused how i will call my method

Comment: React.useEffect(() => {
    // code to run on component mount
    myMethod();
  }, [])

Comment: Should I set myref to every time it changes perform this function or execute only once?

Comment: it will execute once. Only when your component mount. If you need that to change you have to use React.useState

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this.

```
<div ref={handleOverlayRef} style={overlayFixed ? fixedOverlayStyle : overlayStyle}>
```

```
const handleOverlayRef = (c) => {
  console.log(c);
  if (!overlayRect && c) {
    setOverlayRect({ overlayRect: _.pick(c.getBoundingClientRect(), 'height', 'width') })
  }
}
```

Comment: i try buy samee :(

Comment: please share your console.log result.

Comment: <div style="float: left; margin: 0em 3em 1em 0em;"><div class="ui vertical labeled icon menu" style="position: relative; left: 0px; transition: left 0.5s ease 0s;"><div class="item"><i aria-hidden="true" class="twitter icon"></i>Twitter</div><div class="item"><i aria-hidden="true" class="facebook icon"></i>Share</div><div class="item"><i aria-hidden="true" class="mail icon"></i>Email</div></div></div>

Comment: and after i got one null

Comment: i got this div and null

Comment: Okay please add exception.

Comment: Hello I think the problem is the other remained the same error my console.log appears my div