# Property getBoundingClientRect does not exist on type ParentNode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Was trying to use getBoundingClientRect like:

```
const menuWrapper = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
const parentNode = menuWrapper?.current?.parentNode;

const { top, left, height, width } = parentNode?.getBoundingClientRect();

return (
   <div ref={menuWrapper}>
     ...
   </div>
)
```

But currently can't pass typescript error:
`Property 'getBoundingClientRect' does not exist on type 'ParentNode'.`
Anyone that know a way around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react: element.getBoundingClientRect is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963089/react-element-getboundingclientrect-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `parentElement` instead of `parentNode`.

```
const parentEl = menuWrapper?.current?.parentElement;
```

Also you can take a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685739/difference-between-dom-parentnode-and-parentelement) to understand the difference.

But anyway, since you are using optional chaining, which means everything can be `undefined`, you can't use `top`, `left`, `height`, and `width` like this. At least you will need to add something like

```
if (!parentEl) {
  return;
}
```

before destructuring.

Comment: Thanks Avet, checking if the parentEl is falsy and also adding:
`const parentEl = menuWrapper?.current?.parentNode as HTMLElement;` 
helped passing the error.